# What is and is not recursion?

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm trying to understand what exactly is recursion and have not been able to find an answer to the following.

My current understanding of recursion is that it is anytime a method calls itself.

I.E

```
Menu() 
{
if(i<2)
{Console.WriteLine();}
else
{Menu();}    
}
```

The above is an example of recursion a method calling itself.

What I'm not sure about is a scenario like:

```
Menu() 
{
if(i<2)
{Console.WriteLine();}
else
{Console.WriteLine("Something Went Wrong!"); MenuError();}    
}

MenuError() 
{
Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong!");
Menu();
}
```

If the method calls a method which then calls it is this still recursion ?

Comment: I don't know if it is considered recursive or not. But I do know one thing it is definitely considered: [Reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) (A reentrant function is a function that gets called a 2nd time by the same call stack before the first call is complete)

Comment: Suppose I have a set of methods.  Suppose I draw a directed edge from one method to another (possibly itself) if it has code to "call" it (assume that all code is reachable).  Recursion, in terms of graph theory, is anytime there is a cycle, self or otherwise.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=recursion     If the same thread "runs back" sooner or later to call the function it is executing, it is recursion. There is no conceptual difference between your examples, the point is that it calls the function again before it returned from the earlier call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My current understanding of recursion is that it is anytime a method
>   calls itself.

That is correct. Recursive definitions are self-referencing definitions.

Two interesting properties of recursive definitions are *productivity* and *termination*. A program is productive if it continues to yields output, though the full output may never come (hence it may not terminate). A program terminates if it yields its full output in finite time.

For example, this is a productive, non-terminating program:

```
Naturals(int i) {
  Console.WriteLine(i);
  Naturals(i + 1);
}
```

This is a terminating program:

```
UpToTen(int i) {
  Console.WriteLine(i);
  if (i < 10) UpToTen(i + 1);
}
```

This is a non-productive program:

```
DoNothing() {
  DoNothing();
}
```

---

If `Menu` calls `MenuError`, and `MenuError` calls `Menu`, this is sometimes called *mutual recursion*. The only difference is our organisation; we can rewrite the code to just have one method by inlining `MenuError`.

```
Menu()  {
  if (i < 2) {
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("Something Went Wrong!");
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong!");
    Menu();
  }
}
```

You can in fact abstract recursion itself:

```
// General definition
A Fix<A>(Func<Func<A>,A> f) {
  return f(() => Fix(f));
}

// Special definition for void functions
void Fix(Action<Action> f) {
  f(() => Fix(f));
}

void Menu(Action menu) {
  if (i < 2) {
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("Something Went Wrong!");
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong!");
    menu();
  }
}

Fix(Menu);
```

Here is another example using `Fix` to define the factorial function.

```
Func<int, int> Fac(Func<Func<int, int>> fac) {
  return i => i == 0 ? 1 : i * fac()(i - 1);
}

// Fix<Func<int, int>>(Fac)  is the factorial function
```

You may wonder why `Fix` does not have the signature `A Fix<A>(Func<A,A> f)` instead. This is because C# is a strict language, meaning it evaluates arguments before it evaluates function application. With the simpler signature the C# program would end up in infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you that is a really great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is still recursion. There are different types of recursion like Tail recursion, Tree Recursion etc. You can check out google for rest.

By the way, in the second case, if value of i is greater than or equal to 2, you will get stack overflow error as each one will call another one.

Comment: It was really for example purposes only. So incursion is just anytime something a method calls calls that method ?

Comment: @Spooler: I'd say that is true.